# When trying to convert a UITextField text to Int Xcode 7 gives me an error

Tags: ios, int, textfield, swift2, xcode7-beta3

I'm new to programming and after doing some tutorials online I decided to make my own app with Xcode 7 to be able to run my app on my iPhone. But when I try to get input data from a text field and put it into a var it gives me an error. I have tried to use the following:

```
var initialChips = 0
var initialBlind = 0

@IBOutlet weak var txtBlind: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtChips: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var doneBtn: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func doneBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    let initialChips:Int? = Int(txtChips.text)
    let initialBlind:Int? = Int(txtBlind.text)
}
```

Xcode will ask to put a "!" after ".text" but after doing that it gives me a warning: "Initialization of immutable value 'initialChips' (or 'initialBlind' was never used: consider replacing with assignment to '_'or removing it".

What can I do to set a value to my var?

Comment: That warning is not that important, actually. It just warns you that you have never used what you assigned. It must gone when you use initialBlind / Chips in your func.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that the `let initialChips:Int? = Int(txtChips.text)` generates a new variable called `initialChips` (different from the variable from the class). The difference between `let` and `var` is that `let` is inmutable and var is not. You should do:

```
initialChips = Int(txtChips.text)
```

To assign the integer from the `UITextField` to your class variable rather than declaring a new inmutable variable (with the same name) and do nothing with it.

Of course, the same happens with `initialBlind`

**EDIT:**

Try the following:

```
@IBAction func doneBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let initialChips = Int(txtChips.text!) {
        self.initialChips = initialChips
    }else {
        self.initialChips = 0
    }

    if let initialBind = Int(txtBind.text!) {
        self.initialBind = initialBind
    }else {
        self.initialBind = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I do that it gives me an error and makes me use initialChips = Int(txtChips.text!)! to be able to run the code and when I try to print() it doesn't print.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `!` after the closing parenthesis, not after `.text`, like so:

```
let initialChips:Int? = Int(txtChips.text)!
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I try to run the code it asks me to put the "!" after ".text" and when I try to print it doesn't gives me the print in the log.

Comment: really? what version of Swift (or Xcode) are you using?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 7 with Swift 2 but the answer above resolved my problem. Thanks!